# QPainter::drawImage when QPoint is not (0,0)

Tags: qt, drawimage, qpainter

I've got a problem with QPainter::drawImage. I've got KameleonVNC widget to access my app to VNC server. And i have putted it on QFrame. But it is drawing image in top left corner nad i don't like that. I just watched the code and see that image from VNC server drawing with `QPainter::drawImage` with `QPoint(0,0)` or `QRect` with coordinates 0,0. But When i changed coordinates to something else i've got unpredictable result. I've got that it's drawing small pictures only where picture had changed. But i don't understand how to fix this bug with drawImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  translate( x, y ) the QPainter

Comment: well , then if i was you i do traslate the Qframe ... if you need to have the frame at 0,0  you can create an intermediate child QWidget or so , translate it and paint it over